# Explaining/translating Python class for .NET

Tags: python, arrays, vb.net

To be honest, over the years I've been programming, I've never had much cause to work with byte arrays (unless you count copy/paste code for specific purposes) and, in most cases, I admit that I don't totally understand how to handle them properly. Now, I'm trying to parse the `dnsRecord` property of an Active Directory `dnsNode` object, which is a byte array with the following structure:

> - **DataLength** (*2 bytes*): An unsigned binary integer containing the length, in bytes, of the Data field.
> - **Type** (*2 bytes*): The resource record's type. See **`DNS_RECORD_TYPE`** ([section 2.2.2.1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dnsp/39b03b89-2264-4063-8198-d62f62a6441a)).
> - **Version** (*1 byte*): The version number associated with the resource record attribute. The value **MUST** be `0x05`.
> - **Rank** (*1 byte*): The least-significant byte of one of the **RANK*** flag values. See **`dwFlags`** ([section 2.2.2.2.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dnsp/ac793981-1c60-43b8-be59-cdbb5c4ecb8a)).
> - **Flags** (*2 bytes*): ***Not used***. The value **MUST** be `0x0000`.
> - **Serial** (*4 bytes*): The serial number of the `SOA` record of the zone containing this resource record. See **`DNS_RPC_RECORD_SOA`** ([section 2.2.2.2.4.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dnsp/dcd3ec16-d6bf-4bb4-9128-6172f9e5f066)).
> - **TtlSeconds** (*4 bytes*): See **`dwTtlSeconds`** ([section 2.2.2.2.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dnsp/ac793981-1c60-43b8-be59-cdbb5c4ecb8a)). This field uses big-endian byte order.
> - **Reserved** (*4 bytes*): This field is reserved for future use. The value **MUST** be `0x00000000`.
> - **TimeStamp** (*4 bytes*): See **`dwTimeStamp`** ([section 2.2.2.2.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dnsp/ac793981-1c60-43b8-be59-cdbb5c4ecb8a)).
> - **Data** (*variable*): The resource record's data. See **`DNS_RPC_RECORD_DATA`** ([section 2.2.2.2.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dnsp/38b87392-7f61-4e30-9263-9f0fb832d084)).

Looking at a sample of data from one of my AD objects, I believe I at least have an idea of what I'm looking at and how I can find the information I need.

```
04  00  01  00  05  240  00  00  36  43  78  120  00  00  14  16  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  192  168  1  120
```

Even so, what I really want is to put together some form of processing for this information for a project I'm working on. Like I said, I could probably cobble something together based on the sample data I'm looking at that would "do the job", but I'd really like to build it "correctly".

I found an [example written in Python](https://github.com/dirkjanm/adidnsdump/blob/master/adidnsdump/dnsdump.py) that defines a generic `DNS_RECORD` class as well as some more specific classes for the individual record types (`A`, `AAAA`, `SRV`, *etc.*) I understand the basic functionality but, since my understanding is that Python doesn't really use explicit object type definitions and such - and since I usually do my programming in VB.NET - I'm a little confused by the class definition:

```py
class DNS_RECORD(Structure):
    """
    dnsRecord - used in LDAP
    [MS-DNSP] section 2.3.2.2
    """
    structure = (
        ('DataLength', '<H-Data'),
        ('Type', '<H'),
        ('Version', 'B=5'),
        ('Rank', 'B'),
        ('Flags', '<H=0'),
        ('Serial', '<L'),
        ('TtlSeconds', '>L'),
        ('Reserved', '<L=0'),
        ('TimeStamp', '<L=0'),
        ('Data', ':')
    )
```

As I understand it, I get that this is defining the object's properties (`DataLength`, `Version`, `Data`, *etc.*). From what I can "translate" myself through basic context clues and my reading of the standard definitions above, the `Version`, `Flags`, `Reserved`, and `TimeStamp` properties are being set to constant values. That's about as far as I can get with what I "know" about this structure (*which, I have no doubt, could still be wrong*).

What I'm most confused by, however, is, what are the angle brackets there for (*e.g.*, `<H` or `>L`)? I assume it helps to parse out the individual bytes, perhaps by identifying the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)? Are the `H`, `L`, `B` an additional way to specify how the bytes are read/written? I'm just not sure how to replicate these specific directives in .NET.

I'm trying to read up on Python, but any insight into explaining this class definition so I can translate it would be greatly appreciated. I really want to educate myself a bit here.

Comment: All I can say is, the `DNS_RECORD` class you define inherits from a `Structure` (uppercase S) class which is defined in the `impacket` library (see the `import` statement). The parameters for the `structure` (lowercase s) member are specific to that library/class, and so is the way they are expressed. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be documented online (maybe if you install the library you'll get some docs).

Comment: But depending on what you want to use that data for, you may not even need that tool

Comment: Ahh. Okay. I suppose I should've looked a bit beyond just the class definition for more context. I mistakenly assumed that this definition was something "standard" within Python. Looks like I've got a lot more digging to do. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The intention of this data is to build a list of the A records from the AD DNS that I can compare with any/all of the IP addresses assigned to any/all of the NIC's on a particular host to determine what names that host will respond to on the local network. It's convoluted and twisty, but several of the servers on my network respond to multiple hostnames for backward compatability purposes with legacy systems, and I was just trying to devise a method for "consolidating" that information in a way I wouldn't have to manually maintain going forward.

Comment: Anyhow that `Structure` seems like a specialized version of the Python Standard Library `struct` module. You may want to [check it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) for general information

Comment: Reading the **Byte Order, Size, and Alignment** section of that page, as well as the **Format Characters** section, that looks like *exactly* what I was asking about:  
`>H` = a big-endian, unsigned short value.  
Looks like I may find a ***LOT*** of useful and relevant information there. Thank you so much for the reference. @gimix I'd say that is the answer I was looking for. Please post it as such and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DNS_RECORD` class you define inherits from a `Structure` (uppercase S) class which is defined in the `impacket` library (see the `import` statement). The parameters for the `structure` (lowercase s) member are specific to that library/class, and so is the way they are expressed. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be documented online (maybe if you install the library you'll get some docs).

Anyhow that `Structure` seems like a specialized version of the Python Standard Library `struct` module. You may want to [check it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) for general information